# Not able to open Share link of watsapp ,Gmail On cordova in app browser

Tags: cordova

```
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {

            this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        screen.orientation.lock('portrait'); 
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
        if (networkState !== Connection.NONE) {
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.syncaridebeta.com', '_intent', 'location=no,toolbar=no,usewkwebview=yes,clearcache=no,clearsessioncache=no,cleardata=no,disallowoverscroll=no');
        }else{
            console.log('No Internet');
        }

        window.open = ref;

    },
}
```

Not able to open Share link  of watsapp ,Gmail,facebook On cordova in app browser.after placing order showing share link when user click on those links app not doing anything.just clicking happening.above code for index.js file

Below code for config.xml

> Instagolocal
>       
>          Shop for 1000s of products from your nearby stores like grocery, meat, household items, personal care items etc.
>       
>       
>           Krafty Cordova Team
>
> ```
>     <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-portrait-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
>     <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-portrait-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
>     <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-portrait-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
>     <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-portrait-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
>
>     <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
> </platform>
> <platform name="ios">
>     <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
>     <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
>     <icon height="180" src="res/ios/Icon-App-60x60@3x.png" width="180" />
>     <icon height="60" src="res/ios/Icon-App-60x60@1x.png" width="60" />
>     <icon height="120" src="res/ios/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png" width="120" />
>     <icon height="76" src="res/ios/Icon-App-76x76@1x.png" width="76" />
>     <icon height="152" src="res/ios/Icon-App-76x76@2x.png" width="152" />
>     <icon height="40" src="res/ios/Icon-App-40x40@1x.png" width="40" />
>     <icon height="80" src="res/ios/Icon-App-40x40@2x.png" width="80" />
>     <icon height="57" src="res/ios/Icon-App-57x57@1x.png" width="57" />
>     <icon height="114" src="res/ios/Icon-App-57x57@2x.png" width="114" />
>     <icon height="72" src="res/ios/Icon-App-72x72@1x.png" width="72" />
>     <icon height="144" src="res/ios/Icon-App-72x72@2x.png" width="144" />
>     <icon height="167" src="res/ios/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
>     <icon height="29" src="res/ios/Icon-App-29x29@1x.png" width="29" />
>     <icon height="58" src="res/ios/Icon-App-29x29@2x.png" width="58" />
>     <icon height="87" src="res/ios/Icon-App-29x29@3x.png" width="87" />
>     <icon height="50" src="res/ios/Icon-App-50x50@1x.png" width="50" />
>     <icon height="100" src="res/ios/Icon-App-50x50@2x.png" width="100" />
>     <icon height="167" src="res/ios/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
>
>      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
> </platform>
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~3.1.0" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="~1.2.0" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="~3.0.2" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.3" />
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog" spec="~1.3.1" /> </widget>
> ```

below one added in idex.html

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: why _intent of target value?

Comment: tried with _self also but not working

Comment: try ref.show().  If the inappbrowser opened in hidden mode then it will show the inAppBrowser.

Comment: tried but not working